# string.Contains() and IndexOf() throw FormatException

Tags: c#, string

Why would `myString.Contains(" ")` or `myString.IndexOf(' ')` throw a FormatException "Invalid name format"? This exception is only thrown when there is a space in `myString`.

Comment: what's contained in myString?

Comment: myString when it fails contains "carlos tevez", and it's a string type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the MSDN pages for the `string.Contains` and `string.IndexOf` methods clearly shows that neither of these methods ever throws a `FormatException`.

I can only conclude that it must be another part of the code (possibly a call to `string.Format`?) throwing this exception. Perhaps posting the relevant section of code would help?

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. I don't know why, but the debugger caught the exception on the wrong line of code:

if (!Regex.IsMatch(playerName, @"^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,255}$"))
      throw new FormatException("Invalid name format");

Comment: @Mark: No worries. And yeah, the debugger isn't *always* perfect - especially if you're running it on an optimised assembly.

Comment: Thanks. What is the "Cleanup" badge I just earned?

Comment: @Mark Richman: You got it because you rolled-back changes to your question.